Old, untried motors - usable?
I have a 20+ year old General table saw. It was assembled when new in the 90’s.
I also have a 20+ year old Delta jointer. Its box has never been opened.
Neither tool has ever been plugged in. (Both 110v BTW.)
Is it safe to use them? What steps should be taken before turning on the power?

Hi, welcome to StackExchange. Obviously there are no guarantees with stuff like this but people regularly resurrect power tools, including old jointers, that are many decades older than this (like from the 30s). On really old stuff wiring insulation is a concern (esp on the cord) but that shouldn't be an issue here. I'd be fairly confident myself — I regularly use a B&D drill from the 90s and I 'restored' one from the 70s 2-3 years ago that still works great — but obviously check over, turn on cautiously and be willing to hit the off button fast if something sounds off, then inspect further.

One unrelated thing with the table saw in particular, older US saws tend to have no blade guard or not a good one. Also it may not have a built-in riving knife or splitter prior to a certain date (not sure exactly when). While a guard probably can't realistically be considered a must, a riving knife/splitter is.... so I would recommend extreme caution using if there isn't one of those. [Note you can make and fit one to many old saws if needed, using basic materials and tools, and a bit of ingenuity.] P.S. with both tools use push sticks and other safety measures as appropriate.

I recently unboxed, plugged in and used a Delta bench grinder that had been sitting in my garage since the mid-90s. I had absolutely zero problems with it. You probably won't either. There's only one sure way to find out...

Thanks for the feedback. I’ll report back once I’ve tried.

Jealous and curious: General, or General International? (The former would probably have a Canadian flag sticker on it.) Don’t forget to align the fence on the TS.

Will advise next time I get to my shop (I refuse to call it a garage because that makes family think they can leave stuff there).

Obviously there are no guarantees with stuff like this but as you will see if you look up power-tool restorations on YT and elsewhere, people regularly resurrect old power tools, including jointers, that are many decades older than the tools in question, like from the 30s, 40s and 50s.

Is it safe to use them?

On really old stuff degradation of the wiring insulation is a concern (esp. on the cord) but that isn't likely to be an issue here. With tools of this vintage there would normally be zero degradation to the sheathing on the wiring & cord, but storage conditions and your location may play into that — e.g. there may be difference if stored for all this time in unheated/uninsulated spaces in Arizona or New Mexico versus Pennsylvania or Michigan.
I'd be fairly confident myself — I regularly use a B&D drill from the 90s (built a homemade lathe around it) and I 'restored' another drill from the 70s 2-3 years ago that frankly worked fine even before I touched it — but obviously check over visually for anything glaring and use your own judgement.

What steps should be taken before turning on the power?

After visual inspection, read the manual through and refer to it as you go through the commissioning steps.
Turn on cautiously and be willing to hit the off button fast if something sounds off, then inspect further after unplugging the tool. Obviously with any modern wiring setup if there's anything really off with the electrics it will trip the breaker.
Some additional tool-specific points.
Table saw
Even today, manufacturer-supplied saw blades can be, ah, not good; the uncharitable generally refer to them as junk (although this may be particularly true of bandsaw blades).
The stock blade will cut1, but expect to replace it as the first step in making the saw perform better.
In fact if you hope to use the saw for more than basic carpentry tasks get two blades straight out of the gate — you'll want a dedicated rip blade2, and another crosscut or general-purpose blade, rather than relying on a GP blade for all cuts in all materials.
Older US saws tend to have no blade guard or not a good one. Also it may not have a built-in riving knife or splitter. While a guard probably can't realistically be considered vital (in part because of how tricky they are to retrofit), a riving knife/splitter should be considered a must-have.
If your saw doesn't have the latter I would recommend extreme caution using it. Note however that you can fabricate and install one to many old saws if needed, using basic materials and tools, and a bit of ingenuity.
Jointer
If there's rust on the blades don't worry. You can simply de-rust in white vinegar3 or a commercial rust remover (it doesn't really matter much which you use unless you leave them soaking for ages and ages, multiple days and longer). Careful of the sharp edges when you're scrubbing down after.
Just like with most hand-plane blades you don't have to worry even if there's remaining pitting after the de-rusting. Much or all of it can be removed by honing, and at worst if there's any remaining remember that the jointer is never the last tool to touch the show face of any board, so if any track marks are created they will naturally be taken care of in the next surface-prep step (sanding, scraping or hand planing).

On the basis of these sitting unused for many years I'll assume you aren't up to speed with safe operation so:
Safety notes
You'll want to bring yourself up to speed on this with some careful reading/viewing.
But as a starter, with both tools use push sticks or push blocks — the goal being to keep fingers 6" from the blades at all times — along with other safety measures as appropriate (pressure devices such as feather boards and so forth).

1 You might want to retain it for initial breakdown cuts in sheet goods, and for cutting up dirty material to save wear and tear on your good blades.
2 And you might specifically want one with flat-top grind (FTG) as this will not only rip really well but is superior for "joinery cuts", milling operations including cutting grooves and dados (housings) and rabbets (rebates), cheeks and shoulders on tenons, NB even though some of this is cutting across the grain.
3 Pay zero attention to any doomsayers warning about hydrogen embrittlement as it's quite evident there's no danger of it in this context.

Thanks a ton for taking the time to craft this answer. I haven’t had a chance to try yet but should in the coming couple of days.

You're very welcome. If this is suitable as your chosen Answer please remember to give it the tick, thanks.
